# How to get Form Element Value using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to find value of the input element in a popup window which is being opened from a parent page.

My code is below. I am getting not able to get pc value from input.

```
<html>
<head>
<? 
$pid=$_GET['pid'];
$cart_url = '../cart.php?action=add&p='.$pid;
echo $cart_url;
?>  
</head>

<body>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function sendValue(val){
window.opener.document.getElementById('details_<?=$pid?>').value = val;
window.opener.location.href='<?php echo $cart_url; ?>&pc='.concat(val);
window.close();
window.location.reload();
}
</script>
<form name="selectform">
<label>Enter Price:</label>
<input id="1" name="details_<?=$pid?>" type="text"></input>
<input   type="Submit"  onsubmit="sendValue(this.value)"></input>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using the `getElementById` method, but the ID value is equal 1 no equal "details_<?=$pid?>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
<input id="1" name="details_<?=$pid?>" type="text"></input>
<input   type="Submit"  onsubmit="sendValue(this.value)"></input>
```

Change to:

```
  <input id="details" type="text">
  <input type="button" value='Send...' onclick="sendValue(document.getElementById('details').value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `input` box `id` from

```
<input id="1" name="details_<?=$pid?>" type="text"></input>
```

to

```
<input id="details_<?=$pid?>" name="details_<?=$pid?>" type="text"></input>
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `getElementById`, you have to use pass the id of the element you're trying to get the value from (in this case 1).